# Python: extract integers from the line

Tags: python, regex, string

How to extract three CPU utilization values from something like the following string of three numbers?

```
Total CPU Utilization             83.6%   95.4%   30.7%
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. split the line into tokens (`line.split()`)
2. take the last three tokens (`[-3:]`)
3. strip '%' from each (`token.strip('%')`)
4. convert to float

Doing all that in a one-liner list comprehension, we get:

```
[ float(token.strip('%')) for token in line.split()[-3:] ]
=> [83.6, 95.4, 30.7]
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
s = 'Total CPU Utilization             83.6%   95.4%   30.7%'
print re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', s)
```